# Play audio from Parse via UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, parse-platform, avaudioplayer

I've been working on an app that allows audio to be played from Parse (like a social network), but am having trouble getting the code to not have errors.

My .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TalklineViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIScrollView *wallScroll;

@end
```

My .m file

```
@interface TalklineViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *wallAudioArray;
@end

@implementation TalklineViewController

@synthesize wallAudioArray = _wallAudioArray;
@synthesize wallScroll = _wallScroll;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)getWallAudio
{
//Prepare the query to get all the images in descending order
//1
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"AudioObject"];
//2
[query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    //3
    if (!error) {
        //Everything was correct, put the new objects and load the wall
        self.wallAudioArray = nil;
        self.wallAudioArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];
        [self loadWallViews];

    } else {

        //4
        NSString *errorString = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:@"error"];
        UIAlertView *errorAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:errorString delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [errorAlertView show];
    }
}];

}

-(void)loadWallViews
{
//Clean the scroll view
for (id viewToRemove in [self.wallScroll subviews]){

    if ([viewToRemove isMemberOfClass:[UIView class]])
        [viewToRemove removeFromSuperview];
}

//For every wall element, put a view in the scroll
int originY = 10;

for (PFObject *audioObject in self.wallAudioArray){

    //1
    //Build the view with the image and the comments
    UIView *wallAudioView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, originY, self.view.frame.size.width - 20 , 300)];

    //2
    //Add the image
    PFFile *audio = (PFFile *)[audioObject objectForKey:@"audio"];
    UIButton *userAudio = [[UIButton alloc][[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem audioWithData:audio.getData]];
    userAudio.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, wallAudioView.frame.size.width, 200);
    [wallAudioView addSubview:userAudio];

    //3
    //Add the info label (User and creation date)
    NSDate *creationDate = audioObject.createdAt;
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"HH:mm dd/MM yyyy"];
    //4
    UILabel *infoLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 210, wallAudioView.frame.size.width,15)];
    infoLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Uploaded by: %@, %@", [audioObject objectForKey:@"user"], [df stringFromDate:creationDate]];
    infoLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-ItalicMT" size:9];
    infoLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    infoLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [wallAudioView addSubview:infoLabel];

    //5
    //Add the comment
    UILabel *commentLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 240, wallAudioView.frame.size.width, 15)];
    commentLabel.text = [audioObject objectForKey:@"comment"];
    commentLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:13];
    commentLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    commentLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [wallAudioView addSubview:commentLabel];

    //6
    [self.wallScroll addSubview:wallAudioView];


    originY = originY + wallAudioView.frame.size.width + 20;

}

//7
//Set the bounds of the scroll
self.wallScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.wallScroll.frame.size.width, originY);

}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
// Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
// Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@end
```

The problem line is:

```
UIButton *userAudio = [[UIButton alloc][[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem audioWithData:audio.getData]];
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What error message do you have?

Comment: I have two. 1: No known class method for selector buttonWithType:audioWithData and the second: Expected Identifer are the two errors.

Comment: Why have you decided UIButton should have `buttonWithType:audioWithData` method? I can not find it in parse.com documentation.

Comment: It was more of a guess, I followed this tutorial for the most part, adding in code to fit my need: http://www.raywenderlich.com/19341/how-to-easily-create-a-web-backend-for-your-apps-with-parse. Do you have any suggestions on what I should use to play an audio file instead?

Answer (score 0):

UIButton doesn't have an audioWithData method, so that's the biggest issue here; instead, add a target to the button to play the audio with a seperate method:

```
    UIButton *userAudio = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    [userAudio setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 100, 44)];
    [userAudio setTitle:@"Play Audio!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [userAudio addTarget:self action:@selector(playAudio) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self.view addSubview:userAudio];

- (void)playAudio
{
    // Your audio data and playing code here
    // audio.getData
}
```